# Ethernet over GRE bridging - Proxmox

Tags: proxmox, tunnel, gre

I'm trying to install two proxmox on Online.net server's, and I just realized that their RPN feature doesn't work at all like the OVH vRacks.
Since I need the different VM's on both hypervisors to be able to talk, I want to set up a tunnel (their NAT solution seems ugly and unpractical).

I tried adding this to the /etc/network/interfaces on both (inverting the local and remote on the other one, of course) :

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address  172.16.0.251
    netmask  255.255.0.0
    bridge_ports gretap1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    pre-up ip link add gretap1 type gretap remote 10.x.x.x local 10.x.x.y.y ttl 255 dev eth1 && ip link set gretap1 up
    post-down ip link set gretap1 down && ip tunnel del gretap1
```

That does create gretap1 and vmbr1, gretap1 is in the bridge, but it's state is UNKNOWN :

```
gretap1@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8962 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr1 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 2a:de:a1:5b:c5:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(Same state on both sides)

And I can't ping 172.16.0.25x from each host.
Any idea what I did wrong ? The two eth1 can ping each other, the problem is only with gretap. Guess I could use L2TP but I wanted to try out gre, hearing everyone saying it's very easy to set up. Guess not :)

Comment: Did you get anything in your messages log? That MTU size looks a bit wonky. I wouldn't be too worried about `state UNKNOWN` as long as it says `[..],UP,LOWER_UP>` as virtual interfaces tend to do that. Did the bridge get set as up? What do your routing tables look like? How about firewall rules?

Comment: It was actually really simple, the RPN wasn't up between the two machines. I called Online's support and it seems even though it appeared configured on my side, it really wasn't. They corrected it and everything has been running perfectly since that :)